# What's the meaning of "we are living moments of more and lives of less"?

Tags: meaning

We are highly connected, but we aren’t having that many conversations. We have given up conversation for the efficiency of connection, and we have failed to notice the difference between the two. As Turkle puts it, **“we are living moments of more and lives of less.”** Connections don’t make us vulnerable the way that conversations do; we have control, or we think we do. I started thinking about all the ways that I “connect” with friends, and the frequency with which I do it, compared to the amount of conversations I have face-to-face with them. I wish I had more of the face-to-face, more eye contact, more undivided attention; and it is good that I want that.

Comment: The *meaning* is that increasingly we engage in relatively shallow / brief (online) social interactions (encapsulated "moments" that you can refer back to, share with others, etc.) rather than "real life" interactions with better contextual feedback / immediacy / emotional connection. The precise syntax is at least "tricksy" if not downright flawed. Note that ***and*** is an understated alternative to ***but*** here. It's not *quite* the same as saying *We're living more "moments" but less "lives"*, but it's in that general area.

Answer (score 1):

> We are living moments of more and lives of less.

This is a poetic statement.  It is not grammatically correct as the words that "more" and "less" modify have been omitted.  We call this [poetic license](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/poetic-licence) wherein we acknowledge that poets will bend (and sometimes break) the rules of grammar to make their writting more emotionally or philisophically effective.

A complete sentence might read:

> We are living moments of [talking] more and lives of [conversing] less.

However, by adding these words I've limited the intended emotional meaning the "poet" intended.

*Moments of more* emotionally describes how we are forcing larger amounts of activity into every moment of our lives.  We post pictures on Facebook, [sound bites](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sound-bite) on Twitter, and we're doing it constantly.  So, every moment is filled with more activity.

*Lives of less* emotionally describes how much the quality of our lives and interpersonal relationships has declined because we no longer engage in meaningful conversation wherein we learn both what someone did and about the person themselves.  Without true conversation, one might argue, we cannot have true friendships.

So, if Turkle will forgive my interpretation, he suggests that in our effort to accomplish more in every moment, we have lost the meaningful essence of living life.

Comment: Another complete sentence to facilitate parsing might be something like *We **experience** [are living through] **moments of** [life] more and **lives of** [life] less*. But I'll happily grant poetic license for the version as presented.